# What are the IDs for the various Ethereum chains?

Tags: blockchain, signature

I'm looking to find the chain ID's for each network (homestead, etc.). I believe the v-value of signatures is associated with these to some extent.

I'm also under the impression that the ropsten ID is 3, if that gives any context to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `1` Mainnet: https://ethereum.org
- `2` Morden  Testnet (deprecated)
- `3` Ropsten Testnet (deprecated)
- `4` Rinkeby Testnet (deprecated)
- `5` Goerli Testnet: https://goerli.net
- `42` Kovan Testnet (deprecated)
- `11155111` Sepolia Testnet: https://sepolia.dev

See also: https://chainlist.org/

Comment: As found in the go-ethereum code: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/745a3adebd9f98e9d53a7d07519d415b55fa5d1f/cmd/utils/flags.go#L118

Comment: Or, as found in this exhaustive [community wiki](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17101/24693) answer :)

Comment: 4 Rinkeby Testnet

Comment: The list from the EIP can be found at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155#list-of-chain-ids