# What is chainID? Raw transaction from myEther wallet

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, raw-transaction

So I just ran a function from a contract on Ropsten from myetherwallet.com.  It ran fine via metamask, but I was just wondering what chainID was in the rawTx file?

```
{
 "nonce":"0x2e",
 "gasPrice":"0x04e3b29200",
 "gasLimit":"0x14b40f",
 "to":"0x8d3cbc2cba343b97f656428eafa857ee01bda53b",
 "value":"0x2386f26fc10000",
 "data":"0x412a5a6d",
 "chainId":3
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chainid was added about 1 year ago in order to prevent replay attacks across channels. This was due to the ETH / ETC fork, but also applies to testnet and alternate chains (like Expanse). [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids) you can find a list of *well known* chainId values.

You can read about the discussion surrounding replay protection & EIP-155 here: https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/155

Comment: Awesome stuff to know.  The sad part is that it doesn't explain why my transaction won't work, but that's a different question