# What is a chainID in Ethereum, how is it different than NetworkID, and how is it used?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis

Here it's described in Ethereum's go implementation.

```
type ChainConfig struct {
    ChainId *big.Int `json:"chainId"` // Chain id identifies the current chain and is used for replay protection
```

A few questions:

1. How is it different than `networkID`?
2. Is `chainID` and `networkID` needed in every block or just the genesis block?
3. Can you give a specific example of what it means when it says `chainID` is used "for replay protection"?

**EDIT:** Still unanswered:

What would happen in the situation that you set `networkID` to one of the mainnet `networkID`s, but change the other config variables to whatever you want? Why does it matter what you set for networkID if you're running a local chain?

Comment: My uniswap transactions can’t go through because it says no chainid
How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> How is it different than networkID?

ChainID was introduced in [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) to prevent replay attacks between the main ETH and ETC chains, which both have a networkID of `1`.

It's basically just an additional way to tell chains apart. Subsequent to EIP-155, ETH has a chainID of `1`, while ETC has a chainID of `61` (even though they still have the same networkID of `1`).

> Is chainID and networkID needed in every block or just the genesis block?

It's required for the chain to operate in general - e.g. it's required when signing transactions, meaning transactions signed on the ETH network end up with a different hash than those signed on ETC. Before EIP-155, signed transactions on each network would look the same, and could be replayed.

**Edit:**

A specific example of how chainId is used.

As per the [EIP-155 page](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md#specification), the `v` value of a transaction's signature is dependent on the value of chainID.

> If `block.number >= FORK_BLKNUM` and `v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35` or `v =
>   CHAIN_ID * 2 + 36`, then when computing the hash of a transaction for
>   purposes of signing or recovering, instead of hashing only the first
>   six elements (i.e. nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data), hash
>   nine elements, with `v` replaced by `CHAIN_ID`, `r = 0` and `s = 0`. The
>   currently existing signature scheme using `v = 27` and `v = 28` remains
>   valid and continues to operate under the same rules as it does now.

There is a detailed [example](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md#example) of how this is applied on the EIP-155 page.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this works on a granular level? I appreciate the response, but I'm not any closer to understanding _how_ it works when signing, why the hash would be different, etc.

Comment: I've added some further details (essentially copied from the EIP-155 page). :-)

Comment: You say "It's required for the chain to operate in general", but how does a transaction at the _end of the chain_ know about the variables such as `chainID` at the genesis block?

Comment: A client can't operate without knowing which network (i.e. the combination of networkID and chainID) it's operating on. To boot into a network a client's genesis information must match the rest of the network. Note there's technically no "genesis block". It's really just a state definition in a JSON file, one field of which is the chainID. (The first block was block 0, and it was just a normal block, like all subsequent blocks, with the exception that I think it was crafted by hand, and not mined.)

Comment: The client therefore has the genesis information, in its `genesis.json`, which it can refer back to when it needs it. (On boot it'll likely read the genesis state from disk into a set of in-memory variables. I haven't looked at the codepath to confirm though.)

Comment: Right, but if a miner gets a transaction from a _different node_, how can the miner know if the genesis file on that other node matches the one on his mining node?

Comment: Because when he receives the transaction, recovers the `v` value and ultimately the chainID value, it won't match his own. (Which is what EIP-155 is about.)

Answer (score 10):

Despite the fact that this question has an accepted answer, the original question does not seem to be answered, so I will add my two cents.

> 1. How is it different than networkID?

Network identifier (networkID) protects a node from connecting to the nodes that are synchronizing with other networks.  When connection between two nodes is established, these nodes exchange [Status](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/caps/eth.md#status-0x00) messages that, among other things, contain network identifiers of the sending nodes.  According to the documentation, `Status` message “should be sent just after the connection is established and prior to any other eth protocol messages”.  When a node receives `Status` message from its peer, it compares the network identifier in the message with the node's own network identifier and terminates connections in case of mismatch.

Chain identifier (chainID) introduced in [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) protects transaction included into one chain from being included into another chain.  Basically, chain identifier is an integer number being used in the processes of signing transactions and verifying transaction signatures.  If different chain identifiers are used for signing and verifying the transaction, then transaction verification will fail.

> 2. Is chainID and networkID needed in every block or just the genesis block?

Network ID is not included into blocks, nor is it used when signing transactions or mining blocks.  It is just an attribute of Ethereum Wire protocol that prevents nodes of different chains to connect to each other.  Chain ID is not included into blocks, but is used during transaction signing and verification processes, effectively protecting transaction aiming one chain to appear on another chain.

> 3. Can you give a specific example of what it means when it says chainID is used "for replay protection"?

If two chains use different chain identifiers for verifying transactions, or if one chain implemented EIP-155 and the other chain didn't implement it, such two chains will never both accept the same transaction.  This effectively protects from replay attack, i.e. from the situation when a transaction meant to be executed on one chain was actually executed on another chain as well.

Answer (score 5):

**- How is it different than networkID?**

networkId is for node communication and chainId is used for target chain identification in signature - ETC and ETH chainId is different and networkId is same

**- Is chainID and networkID needed in every block or just the genesis
block?**

This is only in the genesis file, not in blocks. Here is the description of the very first block of the mainnet (yeah, I'm currently syncing in fast mode :D )

```
> eth.getBlock(0)
{
  difficulty: 17179869184,
  extraData: "0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa",
  gasLimit: 5000,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000042",
  number: 0,
  parentHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 540,
  stateRoot: "0xd7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544",
  timestamp: 0,
  totalDifficulty: 17179869184,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}

> web3.eth.chainId()
"0x5b7d"
```

**- Can you give a specific example of what it means when it says chainID
is used "for replay protection"?**

You may find your answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/25820/20808)

Comment: What would happen in the situation that you set `networkID` to one of the mainnet networkIDs, but change the other config variables to whatever you want? Why does it matter what you set for `networkID` if you're running a local chain?

Comment: My knowledge on  this topic is not good enough to answer that. I can only tell you that no matter the chainID, geth uses the entire genesis file to check if two peers are using the same chain.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the distinction between the genesis file and the first block? How does the blockchain use this information if it's not stored in the first block?

Comment: Geth just check the genesis.json and compare it to the one of the person trying to connect, that's it. Moreover, the genesis file is a description of the chain at the very beginning. The first block is just a block that uses this description, then it goes on.

Comment: Yes but what if the genesis file says something like "Fork at block 20000", which it does. How does that take place if it's just read at the beginning? Doesn't it need to be read all the time?

Comment: I am having a hugely difficult time understanding the transactions that occur in the first block (always the same), the genesis state file, and if a new EIP is accepted how that changes what the blockchain looks like

Comment: What do you mean "Fork at block 20000"? The genesis cannot say "hey I want a fork at this block"

Comment: There will be a transaction only if someone sent one. Why do you think it would be differet? It's just a normal block @AlwaysQuestioning

Comment: On the description `chainID` does not show up @Florian Castelain

Comment: Other answers state that chainID and networkID are different things with different purposes. Is this answer incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

> What would happen in the situation that you set networkID to one of the mainnet networkIDs, but change the other config variables to whatever you want? Why does it matter what you set for networkID if you're running a local chain?

In order to have a truly local chain, you must set `--bootnodes` to point to one of your nodes. To which bootnode(s) a node connects determines which peers it sees. Then the network id determines with which peers (out of those it sees) it connects.

So if you set `--bootnodes` to one of your nodes, you can set the network id to whatever you want -- you are now separate from the public Ethereum network.

If you don't set `--bootnodes` to one of your nodes:

In this case you don't really have a fully local chain -- you are connected to all the peers on the public Ethereum network that use the same network id as you.

You are not clear what you mean by "other config variables". If you mean chain id or genesis block content, your node will then still connect to peers on the same bootnodes with the same network id, but the hash of the genesis block (and all subsequent blocks) won't match, and the node will feel rather lonely... it will have difficulty finding a peer with which it can exchange blockchain data.