# How get network ID with ethers.js?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

Using web3js it is possible get network ID using the following method:

```
// Contract ABI Load
const ABISimpleStorage = require("./build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json");

// Besu Connection Web3 Load
let web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:8546")
);
    const netID = await web3.eth.net.getId();
```

How we could do same thing in ethers.js?

```
const ABISimpleStorage = require("./build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json");
let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();

let contract = new ethers.Contract(
  ABISimpleStorage.networks["2020"].address,
  ABISimpleStorage.abi,
  provider
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

```
const { chainId } = await provider.getNetwork()
console.log(chainId) // 42
```

Comment: is it safe to assume 1 for homestead, 3 for ropsten etc as a constant?

Comment: @dcsan yes that would be safe to assume

Answer (score 9):

I was searching this today.

Try `provider.getNetwork().chainId`.

`getNetwork().name` gives human readable name like 'homestead'

Comment: catch 22 that to get a provider you need to give a network: 
`let provider = await ethers.getDefaultProvider(network, Settings); `

Comment: I've just found this out after trying to port my web3 to ethers and it's made me sad!

Comment: provider.getNetwork() returns a promise

Comment: It works !  `const network = await provider.getNetwork();
const chainId = network.chainId;`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `provider.getNetwork()` function. It will return a Network type and in it contain the chainId. You can see in the doc here: https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#id2

UPDATE: as it turn out i was wrong the chainID and networkID are the same most of the time, not all of the time and there aren’t any api in etherjs so you need to use json-rpc instead. To do that you use this: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcProvider-send. Where the method is “net_version” and the params is an empty array. It will return like this: https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#net_version.

Comment: Unfortunately, in ethers.js version 5, the chain id returned in `provider.getNetwork()` differs from the network id. Or in other words, in ethers.js version 4, the network id was returned instead of the chain id. So this does not work anymore.

Comment: @ Marc Wäckerlin chainId and networkId are the same but with different name that's all: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37536/50595

Comment: chainId and networkId are not the same.

Comment: catch 22 that to get a provider you need to give a network:
`let provider = await ethers.getDefaultProvider(network, Settings);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for ^6.3.0 version of ethers.js:

```
let userProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(provider);
let objectNetwork = await userProvider.getNetwork();
// returns a bigint
let chainId = parseInt(objectNetwork.chainId.toString());
```