# Is it possible to change the network id in GETH once geth is initialized?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis

I want to change the `network_id` of my private ethereum network setup with geth. It seems like I have to change it in **genesis.json** file and  also have that id when I start `geth`.

But, to apply the change made in **genesis.json** I have to again do `geth init` and this will now start behaving as fresh network and I will loose my blocks. So is there any other way to change network_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this will now start behaving as fresh network and I will loose my blocks

If you have changed the *chain* ID in the `genesis.json` file, then the blocks from your old network won't be valid on the new network, so you will need to start again.

[EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) - which added replay attack protection - has this to say:

> If block.number >= FORK_BLKNUM and CHAIN_ID is available, then when
> computing the hash of a transaction for the purposes of signing,
> instead of hashing only six rlp encoded elements (nonce, gasprice,
> startgas, to, value, data), you SHOULD hash nine rlp encoded elements
> (nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, chainid, 0, 0)

So any transactions on your original network will have been signed in the context of the original network's chain ID<sup>1</sup>. They will be invalid on your new chain, which has a different chain ID.

<sup>1</sup> There's an important distinction between *network* ID and *chain* ID. See [What is a chainID in Ethereum, how is it different than NetworkID, and how is it used?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37533/what-is-a-chainid-in-ethereum-how-is-it-different-than-networkid-and-how-is-it/37536).