# Can my funds be stolen by signing a defi contract in another network?

Tags: ether, metamask, security, pancakeswap, defi

I'm starting to use metamask and I noticed that I'm able to change the network of the same address, so —after digging a little in the web— I now know that every new public address is created from the same private key, so that's why I have the same public address in each of the networks.

I've started to use a new DeFi (a pancakeswap fork) to provide liquidity with high APY and, to interact with it, I'm using the *X network*, using the same Ethereum address of course. So, to get my revenue there, I have to sign a contract and I guess that this contract is allowing them to use all my funds... so I want to know:

- Is the DeFi also available to use my ETH funds in the Ethereum network?
- Can this DeFi use all my funds from my *X network*  wallet? or just the ones of the liquidity swap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of contract you are interacting with, but typically they ask your permission to withdraw token A from your wallet. Or to send the native asset directly to some address. But there's no way for a contract to ask to get access to all of your assets with one transaction (unless you only have one type of tokens in your wallet).

Furthermore, transactions include `chainId` and `networkId`. Those two are used to identify the used network, and the combination should be unique. A transaction signed for network X can't be replayed/reused on network Y, because those values are different. You can read more about those fields here: [What is a chainID in Ethereum, how is it different than NetworkID, and how is it used?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37533/what-is-a-chainid-in-ethereum-how-is-it-different-than-networkid-and-how-is-it/71355)

So, to summarize, giving permission to access token A in network X does not give the contract any other access, and the contract can't take other assets from your wallet.