# Ethereum Network ID

Tags: networkid

Hi Stack Exchange community!

In terms of public networks, what is the point of specifying different chain IDs when we could just specify a different Network ID?

I am just confused as to why I would have to specify a different Network ID! Cheers!

Comment: This question was already asked. Please check this [post.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37533/what-is-a-chainid-in-ethereum-how-is-it-different-than-networkid-and-how-is-it)

Comment: Hi @v1bio thank you for your help!