# How can I (efficiently) programatically see if I am on an ETH or ETC chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, ethereum-classic, blockchain-fork

if i have 2 nodes, one ETH and one ETC, and I am writing a program to use these nodes, how can i determine which node I am using at any given time?

the best i can come up with is to check a known block after the fork and simply compare # of tx. I know how many tx are in that block on both chains, so i can differentiate that way.

this seems clunky. is there a better way to do this?

Edit: this is not a duplicate of "Does ETH and ETC uses the same network ID?" because i am not asking about the network id. i am asking about the network as a whole. eth/etc share a network id of `1` for the main network.

Comment: Does [`net_version`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_version) do the trick?

Comment: @smarx I believe Ethereum and Ethereum classic have the same network id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ETH and ETC uses the same network ID?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36305/does-eth-and-etc-uses-the-same-network-id)

Comment: Okay, then my suggestion won't help. But I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one indicated. (That one doesn't seem to have an answer to this question either.)

Comment: `net_version` returns `1` for both (as expected). is there no way to do it besides the way i described (comparing 2 known blocks)?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the block data for block 1920000 using web3. This is the dao fork block so the block hash will be different.

ETC is [0x94365e3a8c0b35089c1d1195081fe7489b528a84b22199c916180db8b28ade7f](http://gastracker.io/block/1920000)

ETH is [0x4985f5ca3d2afbec36529aa96f74de3cc10a2a4a6c44f2157a57d2c6059a11bb](https://etherscan.io/block/1920000)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said in the comments, doesn't look like any RPC commands do the job, but if your script/program has access to the machine where Geth is running (perhaps over `ssh`), you could either try grepping the logs, or killing and restarting Geth to get the log output.

(Having said that, if you have access to the machine, the `datadir` name gives the game away anyway: `.ethereum-classic` vs. `.ethereum`, unless a non-default name was manually specified on node boot.)

**ETC:**

```
$ cat /home/richard/.ethereum-classic/mainnet/log/geth.INFO | grep chainID
I1201 18:56:27.326033 cmd/geth/flag.go:767]         chainID: 61
```

**ETH:**

No similar file to that above, but on restarting Geth:

```
INFO [12-01|19:09:25.456] Initialised chain configuration  config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: ethash}"
```

(I'm assuming - perhaps incorrectly - that in the ETH case `chainID` *does* equate to the chain ID and not network ID. Either way, the absence of a log file you can grep will allow you to deduce it's ETH and not ETC.)