# eth.blockNumber does not match any network's current block

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, nodes, geth-debugging, clients

I set up a geth full node on Rinkeby with the following command: `/usr/bin/geth --syncmode fast --nousb --cache 3072 --trie-cache-gens 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --networkid 4 2>&1`

(Geth is version 1.8.12)

This should be Rinkeby, although when I get the current block:

```
> eth.blockNumber
3922099
```

This doesn't seem to match what's on Etherscan, where the most recently mined block as of this posting was 2601444 for Rinkeby, 3596981 for Ropsten, 5930232 for mainnet.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3922035,
  highestBlock: 3922099,
  knownStates: 11714163,
  pulledStates: 11714163,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

In addition, Rinkeby's ChainData size should by ~50GB if I'm not mistaken, and:

```
$ du -sh chaindata
13G chaindata
```

So I'm scratching my head a bit: what accounts or the discrepancies in blockNumber and ChainData size?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look for `chainId` when you execute `admin.nodeInfo` from geth's console. The id of 4 should be rinkeby as you say (look for others ids https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17101).

Comment: Thanks, got it. Looks like there is a discrepancy in configuration somewhere: during node initialization there is a reference to chainId of 1, then network id of 4

Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1...
...
Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=4

Comment: Also you can pass parameters `--testnet` and `--rinkeby` to geth to select the network you want to connect to. I'd expect that `--networkid` to be more generic and override the default selection it appears to not be the case.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue: I was passing network but not --rinkeby, and it connected to ChainID 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

so, Ethereum has both a chain ID and network ID. Setting network ID only sets the latter, while passing in `--rinkeby` or `--testnet` correctly sets both