# geth node on ubuntu setup question

Tags: nodes, private-key

To run a node on my vps,

1. --rpccorsdomain "mydomain.com" and set maxconnection, can be set at the same time so that only my own website can send rpc call for security, also I use max connection to limit the bandwidth?
2. What is the correct geth command for init node and start node? Do I still need the file CustomGenesis.json?
3. Usually how big the node is? and how long to download?

also, I created some demo account by script lightwallet, I cannot find which one is the private keys from the keystore object:

> {"salt":"FneDYAPZOTF4f4Gdylm3wMlJv7QLMcvGB1+upxjQvE8=","hdPathString":"m/0'/0'/0'","encSeed":{"encStr":"ruohZV2xykidwTOmM0GtijnhaMGP2dMSUGdBJ/Teh8KIO4JvTa5cOgKxpYEoKKVmZwzzpzfsAw3XehDlNUYnYwE+J6jgB2N8JGxbBVufz5IMMjS0QOw0y8ILf35TMxbRcQFkEstcDACfOWrn0B98xzuvnAwNmh4lC0iLSTm8SV8t/HQn/hbfbQ==","nonce":"Ia3VbewxYFRHr1HfFJgGl4VElo80xGE9"},"encHdRootPriv":{"encStr":"nxB7ElsU/VIP7fSHmGwIjPrEEC2HY7XFbnrIW1+NPrpmBr/LduWwR7Rc7l2BcK5P3yGh6ZtTo+Z+aGyuH4smZnFLM+cwKqMhMZGQrkZxeeIEUjosLqhs2iwAaF8BHW5Pb4zzfE0DeX2UuRoJAE70KrdE0Ed22u9v1tv2zF6Clg==","nonce":"BTYyIsI1Oq4tGXBOl4Qvok7E0DXbxa3o"},"version":3,"hdIndex":3,"encPrivKeys":{"14ad302bf56a84cc48a553fb83f703a996f184c0":{"key":"BfZzyE1PsJ14f4ONi7CcBkNmWBx71QlDeNFj8MIBXzv9plyRUka/GaxMzKr60Y8D","nonce":"NcImsJ2MbIjZJEIK8Ho6p3SgawFJk/LR"},"648c78407bf7392de7153515e7b2714cec103709":{"key":"lPpTSyRrIxi16lRiZMIlk2CzPctYTUkZOPkmMNz3U5Qus3zko0SwjLRKo9iKAlLf","nonce":"+JhVJtdKKhnvAvdPEeFYem5IBIBsFZpx"},"cf69e4be058fbdc03f921654cc14b865c9c8cbbe":{"key":"8KVDtJ6cQZ39XKwJqB3QfwZPbJjw9a6JA2gVnHQOdOqMaIGxfgsQYg8N9HY9DLQX","nonce":"7yF0LSgUB+88gaC/kGK+1TkFrSE63WEc"}},"addresses":["14ad302bf56a84cc48a553fb83f703a996f184c0","648c78407bf7392de7153515e7b2714cec103709","cf69e4be058fbdc03f921654cc14b865c9c8cbbe"]}

How can I find the private key for each account? This is just for testing

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to initialize your private node and allow rpc connection to specific port at the same time.

```
geth --datadir ./datadir_new --networkid 2018 --port 30303 --rpc --rpcapi “db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug” --rpccorsdomain=”*” --rpcaddr=”localhost” --rpcport 8545 console
```

Comment: the —networkid 2018, here is it 2018? not 1?

Comment: It would be what you have specified in your genesis block file.         "config": {
    "chainId": 2018,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },

Comment: for main net, is the networkid 1?

Comment: Yes check here. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids/17101

Comment: Thanks, actually how can I find the genesis file and the startup node ?

Comment: You have to create a genesis file and place it in the same directory where you created the datadir. Open geth and read the genesis file using this command. Geth --datadir ./datadir init Init.json   https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0

Comment: {
  "config": {
    "chainId": 2018,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },

  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x400",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use these two flags at the same time
2. The commands can vary depending if you're setting up for a public network or private network. I'll assume you want a to connect to mainnet. So pass the `--mainnet` flag and it will configure everything for you, network ID, genesis, and bootnodes. Same can be done with `--rinkeby` and other known networks.
3. The amount of storage needed by a node varies depending on the network and the synchronization mode. See this page https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast