# About Ethereum testnet 61 (Ethereum Classic)

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, network

I know that Ethereum was forked 2 chains due to DAO hacking. so Ethereum Classic was borned at that time but 2 chains are equal technically. 
Network number is different between Ethereum(number is 1) and Ethereum Classic(number is 61).

1. Is different group of miner between Ethereum and Ethereum Classic?
2. If a end-user generate a transaction with Eth, this transaction should be delivered into the Ethereum network not Ethereum Classic. what happens if a miner in Ethereum network braodcast a transaction to miner that resides in Ethereum Classic?
3. Ethereum has diverse testnet, so how Ethereum network can distinguish the diverse network?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find answers to your questions below:

#### Is different group of miner between Ethereum and Ethereum Classic?

Yes. Although they both use the same minining algorithm and have the same network id (1), Ethereum Classic has a chain id of 61. Therefore they are two completely seperate chains (although technically miners can decided to mine either one of them by switching chain id)

#### If a end-user generates a transaction with Eth, this transaction should be delivered into the Ethereum network not Ethereum Classic. what happens if a miner in Ethereum network braodcast a transaction to miner that resides in Ethereum Classic?

The block would be rejected by ever other miner on the Ethereum Classic chain as it would not solve his witness would not contain the proof of work for the Ethereum Classic Chain.

#### Ethereum has diverse testnets, so how Ethereum network can distinguish the diverse network?

There are multiple forks of Ethereum, all of which differ in chain id or network id.

You can see them here: [How to select a network id or is there a list of network ids?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids)

Comment: Thansk for awesome anwser @Samuel :)
I checked that the block can be distinguishable by separating chain id(you can see EIP-155). 
but, I had a strange idea, a malicious miner can keep two chains(for example ETH, ETC). Think of this way, I have a two machine and one(A) is running on ETH network, another(B) is running on ETC. connection can be established between A and B if I want. A node can delivery the block to B node when it get a propagated block, also vice versa. the benefit which can be given by doing this is that I can mine two types(ETH,ETC) block to earn reward.