# Do testnets ever merge with mainnets?

Tags: blockchain, testnets

Does a testnet ever merge with the mainnet? In other words, if I have ETH on a testnet, will I ever have actual ETH or do testnets remain for testing forever?

I Googled in multiple ways but could never find a simple "No" or "Yes" to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

That would be like money you printed at home rising to the level of actual cash. There is no path where that happens.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Understood. The thing is, I was being rewarded in test coins all this while on Rinkeby for testing of a project. The way they talked was that I was getting ETH or will get it. Thanks for answering my questions, I guess I need to have a serious talk with them now.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding a bit of nuance to Rob's answer.

All Ethereum testnets started with a blank slate and have never and will never sync the balances with mainnet. Don't mistake them for [hard spoons](https://blog.cosmos.network/introducing-the-hard-spoon-4a9288d3f0df), which are blockchains that cloned the balances of another blockchain, but remain independent in all other regards.

Answer (score 0):

No. All networks have different IDs, thats the discriminating them when running on a client. Also, all clients need to speak and sync with the same ID.

Here is a summary of IDs to get an idea. 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17101/5375